# Visual Studio 2012 - Linq2SQL - How to add List as attribute?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have a basic problem:
I have a class "Customer". A Customer has several Email-Adresses. I'd like to add Email as List. I don't see how to do this, there are only "simple" types available for choosing.

thank you very much....
Edit:

I'm using Linq2SQL and trying to set attribute to a complex type. I do not know how to do this as there are only simple types available on the graphical editor...

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using a SQL database as you mentioned it in your question title. Is this with the `Entity Framework` or straight `ADO.NET`?

Comment: @CameronTinker - He said he's using LinqToSql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add it to the object directly.  Instead, you add the association with the database table that stores the email addresses.  Right-click on the designer and choose to add a new association.  Fill out the popup, and it'll create an arrow between them.  That arrow represents your `List<>`.

Comment: I haven't done the database yet - I assumed I could generate it after finishing the class diagramm?

Comment: @Pete - I don't know if L2S supports Code-first, but it doesn't matter.  Just create the new object to represent the table for email addresses, then link them.

Comment: Hi Bobson, thanks I get it now. But what if I have a Class Customer and a Class Email. Email consists of type and adress ("Private" and "test@example.org" for instance...)

Comment: How can I Say Customer has a property of type Email as type and adress belongs together?

Comment: I think I got it - I first need to model the database and set primary/foreign key and relations and then import it into linq, right?

Comment: @Pete - Yep, that's the easiest way to do it.  You can do it manually without the foreign key relationship (which is the method I have in my answer), but it's much easier if that relationship already exists.